# How to return a class value when iterating through a dictionary of said class

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

In this simplified form, I want to return the value of bar1 when I iterator over a dictionary of a class in order to avoid issues with a library which requires a list.

```
class classTest:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.bar1 = foo
    def __iter__(self):
        for k in self.keys():
            yield self[k].bar1

aDict = {}
aDict["foo"] = classTest("xx")
aDict["bar"] = classTest("yy")

for i in aDict:
    print i
```

The current output is

```
foo
bar
```

I am targetting for this output to be

```
xx
yy
```

What am I missing to get this to work?  Or is this even possible?

Comment: You are iterating over `aDict`, a dictionary, which yields the keys. You are not iterating over each individual value. The dictionary doesn't delegate iteration to the values contained.

Comment: `for val in aDict.values()` if you want the values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your not iterating over the classes, but the dictionary. Also your class has no `__getitem__`-Method, so your `__iter__` wouldn't even work.

To get your result you can do

```
for value in aDict.values():
    print value.bar1
```

Comment: This explains why it acted the way it did.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the keys.  Print the values instead:

```
for k in aDict:
    print aDict[k]
```

Or you can just iterate directly over the values:

```
for v in aDict.itervalues():   # Python 3: aDict.values()
    print v
```

The `__iter__` on your `classTest` class isn't being used because you're not iterating over a `classTest` object.  (Not that it makes any sense as it's written.)